# How to turn image data in JSON from WCF Data Services into UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, json, uiimage, wcf-data-services, odata

**How do I get image data out of JSON returned by a WCF Data Service?**

I've got a WCF Data Service serving some objects that include some binary data that is an image (column type in SQL Server is `image`).  It comes across as text gibberish in the JSON.  In the iOS client I'm writing for this service, I want to display this data as an image ([`UIImage imageWitData:myData]`).

Here is what I'm doing:

```
NSData *networkData = nil; //assume this magically gets data from the service
NSError *err = nil;
//assume the returned JSON has one object and is not an array
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:networkData
     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&err];

//handle error if needed

NSString *imageString = [dict objectForKey:@"Image"];
NSData *imageData = [imageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
///The service is using UTF-8.
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Putting that `image` in a `UIImageView` doesn't show anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In my case on the .net side the data contract was a string, and was encoded using `dto.Contents = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);`.   Just throwing this in here because the question doesn't really show any of the .net side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that binary data returned from WCF Data Services is base64 encoded.  I'm using the [NSData-Base64](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64) category to parse it, and it's working great.  So the solution looks like this:

```
NSData imageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:imageString];
```

When I imported those files into my project ARC threw up some errors, but I was able to solve them by removing a couple of `autorelease` calls in the .m file.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question and posting the solution, this really helped me!